# How to center i tags inside box jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this icons `fa fa-long-arrow-right` and i want them to be centered inside of my div. How can i achieve that ? Can it be done with bootstrap ?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //portfolio - show link
  $('.fdw-background').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: '1'
      });
    },
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: '0'
      });
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.tiles_border {
  border: 1px #ffffff solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.fdw-background {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px #ffffff solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fdw-background h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.fdw-background p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.fdw-background .fdw-port {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 40px 0;
}

.fdw-background .fdw-port a {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
}


/*subtitle*/

.fdw-subtitle {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: #0CF;
}

.fdw-subtitle a {
  color: #F90;
}

#koncerty {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/400x550");
  height: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/62cf094036.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div id="koncerty" class="tiles_border">
        <div style="opacity: 0;" class="fdw-background atrakcje-tekst">
          <h2>KONCERTY</h2>
          <br>

          <p>Na targach wystąpią:
            <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Andre</i> <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Bobi</i> <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Kosmokwaki</i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do it first is with bootstrap col-offset-4 class on the div that contains the icons what this will do is give you 4 colums of white space
note that class from your div is change from col-md-6 to col-md-offset-4

```
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-12">
            <div id="koncerty" class="tiles_border">
                <div style="opacity: 0;" class="fdw-background atrakcje-tekst">
                <h2>KONCERTY</h2>
                <br>

                <p>Na targach wystąpią:
                    <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Andre</i> <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Bobi</i> <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Kosmokwaki</i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Other way is to set full width column with col-md-12 and center the icons to the center with text-center class

```
<div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <div id="koncerty" class="tiles_border">
                <div style="opacity: 0;" class="fdw-background atrakcje-tekst">
                <h2>KONCERTY</h2>
                <br>

                <p>Na targach wystąpią:
                    <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Andre</i> <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Bobi</i> <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Kosmokwaki</i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt class .text-center in div which will make all the inline element or text to be a center of div.

You can avoid CSS declaration for each i tag to be centred.

Moreover, If u want to make your div wrapper to be center-aligned to the browser, you should use col-md-offset-4 col-md-5 col-sm-12 in div instead of what you have currently used.

Feel free to reply and discuss for more clarification.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //portfolio - show link
  $('.fdw-background').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: '1'
      });
    },
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: '0'
      });
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.tiles_border {
  border: 1px #ffffff solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.fdw-background {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px #ffffff solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fdw-background h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.fdw-background p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.fdw-background .fdw-port {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 40px 0;
}

.fdw-background .fdw-port a {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
}


/*subtitle*/

.fdw-subtitle {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: #0CF;
}

.fdw-subtitle a {
  color: #F90;
}

#koncerty {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/400x550");
  height: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/62cf094036.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div id="koncerty" class="tiles_border">
        <div style="opacity: 0;" class="fdw-background atrakcje-tekst">
          <h2>KONCERTY</h2>
          <br>

          <p>Na targach wystąpią:
            <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Andre</i> <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Bobi</i> <br>
            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true">Kosmokwaki</i>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about to make those icons inline ?

Comment: @bashante : you need not make i tag as inline ...all icons will be in center-aligned when you give the parent element text-center class .

Comment: i meant vertical inline ?